# Autofit doesn't work in worksheet_active() in Excel

Tags: excel

I have these codes to have both workbook opening and switching sheet would have all being wraptext and autofit to make all long data to be muti links:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Me.Sheets
ws.Cells.WrapText = True
ws.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
Next ws
End Sub



Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Me.Sheets
ws.Cells.WrapText = True
ws.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
Next ws
End Sub
```

The workbook open part works, but the worksheet_activate part doesn't. I have few sheets in the workbook, and few field of a sheet is depend on another sheet. After I make change to make a field becomes long, the another sheet result cannot catch up the length and hidden below in the box. I have to retarts the excel in order to let the workbook open part work and all hidden words would be seen again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()` in *each* sheet's code module.  Also, the code in each worksheet needs to be:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Me.Cells.WrapText = True
    Me.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
End Sub
```

as in that context, Me refers to a `Worksheet` object, not a `Workbook` object.

Comment: I find out that I only need to use your codes for every sheet then ok, no need to have the Workbook_Open() codings.